# DUP and DUP2 program. I can't understand how it works

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls

I can't understand how this code works. This program has to copy the text of FILE1 to FILE2 using only getchar and putchar. The part that I don't understand the most is from the first if to the end of the program. In the first lines basically it opens the first file in read-mode, it creates the second file for reading and writing. Then it points fdin to in and fdout to out. Then it assigns 0 to dupin and 1 to dupout and I don't know why somehow it passes the text of the first file to the other one and it also writes "Copy terminated" on FILE2. Can you explain please?

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{

  int  fdin, fdout, dupin, dupout, c;
  FILE *in, *out;

  in=fopen("FILE1","r");
  out=fopen("FILE2","w+");
  fdin=fileno(in);
  fdout=fileno(out);


  if((dupin=dup2(fdin,STDIN_FILENO))<0) 
    printf("dupin error\n");            

  if((dupout=dup2(fdout,STDOUT_FILENO))<0)   
    printf("dupout error\n");               

  while ( (c=getchar()) != EOF) 
          putchar(c); 


printf("Copy terminated\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you use `"w+"` when opening `FILE2`, but that's fairly minor.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually this is my professor's code

Comment: So, now you know that professors are human, subject to the frailties and failings of all humans.  And they may find it harder to get their code reviewed than others (and may have a tendency not to bother).  There's a lot of error checking missing from the code (were the files opened successfully?).  If the `dup2()` calls fail, execution continues.  The error messages should be printed on `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Arguably, it should not write `Copy terminated` to the output file (`stdout`) as it does (because standard output is now `FILE2`) — that should be reported to `stderr` too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I was about to complaint about your comment, but you are definitely right in all about that professor's code. :)  It demonstrates that who knows something does it, and who doesn't know it fully, teaches it.

Answer (score 0):

The could should use [`freopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html); it is designed for this context.

However, the first [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) call in this code makes the file descriptor underlying the `stdin` stream (file descriptor `STDIN_FILENO` or 0) refer to the file descriptor underlying the `in` file stream.  When you read from `stdin` after that, it comes from `FILE1`.

Similarly, the second `dup2()` call makes the file descriptor underlying the `stdout` stream (file descriptor `STDOUT_FILENO` or `1`) refer to the file descriptor underlying the `out` file stream.  When you write to `stdout` after that, it goes to `FILE2`.

There's a risk of confusion if the code also tries to read from `in` or `out` after the `dup2()` calls.  This would be avoided with `freopen()`.
You also don't close `in` or `out` before exiting, even though you opened them.  Normally, it's a good idea to explicitly close what you opened.  The code executed by `exit()` — which is called when `main()` returns — *does* close *all* the open file streams.  You could in principle close `in` and `out` immediately after the `dup2()` calls — they aren't needed any more.

Another, better alternative would be to use `getc(in)` and `putc(c, out)` (good job on using `int c;`) — except that seems to be prohibited by the rules of the question, which is clearly a programming exercise.